# How to give a file path instead of file name c++?

Tags: c++, md5

This  code part is from a simple md5 hash generator.But here i can only give a file name to generate the md5.

```
LPCWSTR NameOfTheFile = L"Test.txt"; //Name of the file that user is scanning
```

But i want to give a file path here instead of the file name..Is there any way to do that.?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define MD5LEN  16


using namespace std;


DWORD main()
{

    MaximizeOutputWindow();

    DWORD cryptStatus = 0;

    BOOL hashResult = FALSE;

    BYTE fileSizeToHash[BUFSIZE];

    HCRYPTPROV cryptProv = 0;

    HCRYPTHASH hash = 0;

    HANDLE file = 0;

    DWORD hashNumbCount = 0;

    DWORD hashRead = 0;

    BYTE getHashValue[MD5LEN];

    CHAR numberConvert[] = "0123456789abcdef"; //hex decimal conversion

    LPCWSTR NameOfTheFile = L"Test.txt"; //Name of the file that user is scanning


    // Logic to check usage goes here.
    file = CreateFile(NameOfTheFile, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);
```

Comment: Are you trying to use an absolute path to a file instead of a relative path?  What happened when you tried that?

Comment: `here i can only give a file name` No, `CreateFile` does take a full path in general, a filename alone is just interpreted as a relative path with the file being in the current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use file paths with `CreateFile`. Try something like `NameOfTheFile =  L"C:\\Text.txt";`